# ODBC connection using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc, connection-string

I am getting an error message when I run my VBA code. I tried debugging and seems like there is something wrong with my connection string. I am getting an error message "Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

```
Sub Macro176()
    Sheets("176Tk").Select

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 17

    Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    oConn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
               "server=myserveraddress;" & _
               "database=mydatabasename; uid= myuserId; pwd=mypassword;" & _
               "option=3"

    SQLstr = "SELECT SUBSTRING(dbo.collection_points.name, CHARINDEX('-', dbo.collection_points.name) + 2, 3) + 'Tk'  AS 'Tank', " & _
             "dbo.data_values.actual_date_time AS 'Date', " & _
             "dbo.data_values.value_text AS 'Drain Time', " & _
             "dbo.data_points.name AS 'Description', " & _
             "dbo.data_values.user_id AS 'Field Operator' " & _
             "FROM " & _
             "dbo.collection_points INNER JOIN " & _
             "dbo.area ON dbo.collection_points.area_rec_id = dbo.area.area_rec_id INNER JOIN " & _
             "dbo.data_points ON dbo.collection_points.cp_rec_id = dbo.data_points.cp_rec_id INNER JOIN " & _
             "dbo.data_values ON dbo.data_points.dp_rec_id = dbo.data_values.dp_rec_id INNER JOIN " & _
             "dbo.system_levels ON dbo.area.ownership_sysid = dbo.system_levels.system_id " & _
             "WHERE " & _
             "((dbo.system_levels.description = 'CX5 Crude Tank Farm' and dbo.area.name = 'Crd TF Draining') OR " & _
             "(dbo.system_levels.description = 'CX5 Melvindale Tank Farm' and dbo.area.name = 'Mel Tank Draining') OR " & _
             "(dbo.system_levels.description = 'CX5 Tank Farm (CP)' and dbo.area.name = 'CP Tank Draining') OR " & _
             "(dbo.system_levels.description = 'CX5 Unifiner Tank Farm' and dbo.area.name = 'LabT.F. Draining')) AND " & _
             "((dbo.data_values.value_text <> 'Yes') AND (dbo.data_values.value_text <> 'Complete') AND (dbo.data_values.value_text <> 'Incomplete') AND " & _
             "(dbo.collection_points.name NOT like '%Roof%')) AND " & _
             "dbo.data_values.nominal_date_time>='2017-01-01 00:00:00' and " & _
             "dbo.data_values.nominal_date_time<'2018-12-31 11:59:59' " & _
             "ORDER BY dbo.collection_points.name, dbo.data_values.actual_date_time"

    rs.Open SQLstr, oConn, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    Do Until rs.EOF
        Sheets("176Tk").Cells(i, 1).Value = rs.Fields("Tank")
        Sheets("176Tk").Cells(i, 2).Value = rs.Fields("Date")
        Sheets("176Tk").Cells(i, 3).Value = rs.Fields("Drain Time")
        Sheets("176Tk").Cells(i, 4).Value = rs.Fields("Field Operator")
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    rs.Close
    oConn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set oConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are using an `ODBC` connection, you would theoretically specify the data source name (located in the ODBC Admin utility). You are specifying a server address. Hence your error implying an invalid data source.

Comment: Is your Excel 32-bit or 64-bit?  If 32-bit, did you install the 32-bit MySQL driver, or the 64-bit one?  You need to have matching 32-bit or 64-bit installs.

Comment: What would be an example of data source name?

Comment: Also do i not need the server address there?

Comment: I have never used an ODBC connection like this without first creating the data source in the ODBC Admin utility (odbcad32.exe) so I can't help you there. My suggestion is to create the data source and reference it by name in the connection string.

Comment: You need to create the MySQL ODBC provider first, like @JacobH suggests. The connection won't work on machines without the DSN configured.

Comment: I did that but now it's giving me another error message. It says "Invalid connection string attribute". Here is my connection string oConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
               "Data Source=myserveraddress;" & _
               "database=mydatabasename; uid=myuserid; pwd=mypassword;" & _
               "option=3"

Comment: Now you're using SQL Server?

Comment: You don't need to put the provider if you pass the data source name. I did have an answer here but I deleted it. I'll undelete it if this helps `"DSN=DataSourceName;uid=UserID;pwd=Password;database=DatabaseName"` Replace those values (Data Source Name = the name you made in the ODBC Admin, etc.) and see if you get it working.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks, everyone