# Loop through files in a given folder, check cell content in CLOSED files to identify template and add said files to array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm mainly trying to work off of the solution in this thread [How to loop through all sheets in all workbooks within a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575181/how-to-loop-through-all-sheets-in-all-workbooks-within-a-folder).

This is the code responsible for filling the array

```
    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop
```

If I understand it correctly, it should loop through all files in a given folder and retrieve every excel file in it.

Based on this thread [ExecuteExcel4Macro to get value from closed workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook) ExecuteExcel4Macro(string) should allow to check/retrieve the content of a given cell in a closed workbook of which I already have its name and its sheet's name.

I want to check the value of a cell (so I can identify whether the file is based on a template which I would like to work on) so it gets added to the array in the first.

I would like to integrate the solution to check cell content into the loop I pasted above.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wbPath As String, wbName As String
    Dim wsName As String, cellRef As String
    Dim Ret As String

    'wbPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\"
    wbPath = "C:\Users\my.name\Desktop\"

    wbName = "QOS DGL stuff.xls"
    wsName = "ACL"
    cellRef = "C3"

    Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
          wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

    MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)
End Sub
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Doesn't look like you have attempted it..

Comment: In your loop `FilesInPath` doesnt seem to be set before starting it?

Comment: I don't think you can retrieve stuff from the files without opening them unless you're using an ODBC connection. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824402/odbc-connection-using-vba                  You will need to enable a Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library under the Tools->References menu. The latest one on my machine is I think 6.1

Comment: You'll need a different connection string though. Something like this: `cn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & your_path_and_file_name_here & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""")` If you search for Excel odbc connection string you should be able to find one that works.

Answer (score 1):

### Check Cell in Closed Files (`ExecuteExcel4Macro`)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessFiles()

    Dim sFolderPath As String
    sFolderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\Documents\Test\"
    Const sExtensionPattern As String = "*.xls*"
    Const swsName As String = "ACL"
    Const sCellAddress As String = "C3"
    Const sString As String = "Yes"

    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sExtensionPattern)

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    Dim cString As String

    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        cString = GetCellString(sFolderPath, sFileName, swsName, sCellAddress)
        If StrComp(cString, sString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' You could process the files here without writing them
            ' to a data structure...
            dict(sFolderPath & sFileName) = Empty
        End If
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop

    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Debug.Print Join(dict.Keys, vbLf)

'    ' ... or loop through the dictionary ...
'    Dim Key As Variant
'    For Each Key In dict.Keys
'        ' Continue
'        'Debug.Print Key
'
'    Next Key
'
'    ' ... or write the values from the dictionary to an array
'    ' and loop through the array.
'    Dim MyFiles As Variant: MyFiles = dict.Keys
'
'    Dim n As Long
'
'    For n = 0 To UBound(MyFiles)
'        ' Continue
'        'Debug.Print MyFiles(n)
'    Next n

End Sub

Function GetCellString( _
    ByVal wbPath As String, _
    ByVal wbName As String, _
    ByVal wsName As String, _
    ByVal CellAddress As String) _
As String
    Const ProcName As String = "GetCellString"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim ee4mString As String
    ee4mString = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
          wsName & "'!" & Range(CellAddress).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    GetCellString = ExecuteExcel4Macro(ee4mString)

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: I keep seeing the ExecuteExcel4 macro. I’ve never used it. Is it truly not opening the files? Or is it an ODBC connection underneath the hood wrapped up in a nice function?